# How to auto play YouTube videos for products?

Tags: magento2, product, video, product-video, youtube

I've uploaded a youtube video to a product in Magento 2.

It's displaying fine, but I want to autoplay that product video in front.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Product Video** (where you entered the YouTube API key).
There should be a field called `Autostart base video`. Set that to `Yes`.

[image: Magento 2 Youtube API]

Comment: Thank you Marius its working, but is there any possible to play when mouse over

Comment: I don't think so. I think you are in youtube territory when you hover the video and you cannot control that, unless the youtube API allows you to.

Comment: @Marius In mobile device why we need to click two time in youtube video ? Is that any solution to click youtube video on once click.

Comment: @hweb87. I have no idea.

Comment: We have enabled this setting, cleared cache, but a YouTube video is not autoloading still on a product page. Any idea how to debug from here to work out the reason please?

Answer (score 0):

**You can add video for product page in Magento 2.**
**I have shared link below,**
https://magenticians.com/add-video-to-product-in-magento-2/

Hope this may help you.